# How to make a route accessible only from localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a route like this:

```
[Route("api/elasticsearch/resync/products")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> ResyncProducts()
{
}
```

How can I make it accessible only from the localhost?

Comment: It should be accessible right away, can you show more details ?
tell us what have you tried and so...

Comment: @MohammadHamoud it is. I want to make in accessible ONLY from localhost.

Comment: try making the port that it is running on, blocked from the firewall

Comment: @MohammadHamoud I want to limit the access only per 1 route not for the whole API. Read the question again.

Comment: I think you can check if the request is from localhost usine `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal`

Comment: You need this for security, so that malicious user cannot call this api from outside?

Comment: @Evk yes. Right now the API only checks is the user is logged in.

Comment: Then CORS is not the right tool. And I'm not sure how you can restrict access to the specific url in firewall. I think my answer (check if caller calls this api from localhost (127.0.0.1) ip) is the right way.

Comment: @Evk yes, my bad, I removed that part of my comment when I figured out that it won't be possible for only 1 URL... I was just brain-storming. :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use action filter and check if request goes from loopback interface:

```
public class RestrictToLocalhostAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var remoteIp = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(remoteIp)) {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Then just decorate action with this attribute:

```
[Route("api/elasticsearch/resync/products")]
[HttpGet]
[RestrictToLocalhost]
public async Task<string> ResyncProducts()
{
}
```

Be careful with `context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`. If you in forward-proxy mode (some other webserver like IIS or Nginx forwards requests to you) - this ip might always be localhost (because it's actually nginx\iis who makes a request to you), or even null, even for remote requests, if you configure your application incorrectly. But if all is configured correctly - that should be fine.

Don't use CORS like other answer suggests. It will not prevent anyone from calling your api from whatever ip. CORS is browser feature, outside of browser (and malicious user will of course not request your api via browser page) - it has exactly zero effect.

Comment: Just asking for a little context on how it doesn't filter IP's? I've tested CORS origin filtering plenty of times and it's worked for me....

Comment: @BrandonMiller CORS is browser feature. It means browser will make a request, evaluate a response (CORS headers) and decide if it's fine to allow that. When you make requests outside of browser (for example with `HttpWebRequest`) - CORS has absolutely zero effect.

Comment: Ahh.. I don't believe I've ever tested CORS outside of a browser.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look into using CORS. Once installed correctly, you should be able to apply an attribute like so
`[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

See here:
https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/09/cors-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: But this limits the whole API not only 1 route.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using .Net Core. Still, this is not limiting the entire API. See the link I posted in my edit. You can still use the attribute method on your controller, and disable CORS for any other method not intended to be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with the help of [Brandon Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321759/9359129) here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#enabling-cors-in-mvc

**Enabling CORS in MVC per action:**

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

and in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com"));
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    // Shows UseCors with named policy.
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Note CORS only works with well behaved clients. It's a weak security boundary. Trusting localhost is also pretty week. You should be using something like a secret API key.

Comment: @Tratcher I authorize only logged in users to use the API. But good comment. #thumbsup